# What is the easyest way to create a settings file in python

Tags: python-3.x, application-settings

I am just making something to start up minecraft with , and I need a way to save some settings to a file , but I have no idea what I should use to do it . I googled my question already and what I got was information about pyYaml configparser and configobj I belive.And after looking at it I got confused because im not to scripting and python. What I would like is a recommendation or a tutorial on using those modules or the modules that you guys suggest . 
I am using python 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `configparser`, and there are examples/tutorial at the end of the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#examples